# Converting hexadecimal to IEEE754 hexadecimal representation

Tags: c

What would be the best way to convert from hexadecimal textual representation to it's IEEE754 representation in double precision (that would result in minimal rounding)?

For example, converting:

`-0x1.f8b791cafcdefp+4`  to  `C03F8B791CAFA2C0`

My current method is to convert from hexadecimal to a `double`, then convert this to IEEE754 representation, but this obviously involves dubious levels of rounding.

Comment: The literal `-0x1.f8b791cafcdefp+4` already *is* a `double`. And it's very likely already in IEEE754 format in memory. So all that's needed is a plain `memcpy` into a `uint8_t` array of `sizeof(double)` elements. Which can then be copied into a `uint64_t` variable. Or you could use type-punning through a `union` which is allowed in C.

Comment: Is the 'input' hex in the form of a character string? If so, the `%la` format for `sscanf` should do the trick.

Comment: Any time that rounding is necessary to parse a hexfloat to a double, this problem inherently requires that rounding, because the output is a double (rendered in hexadecimal). There is no escape. If you needed more precision, the output format would have to be changed to something bigger.

Comment: These replies are perfect, thank you all for being so quick! @Someprogrammerdude will try this and respond if I have any further questions with it, thank you! I didn't realise that a hexadecimal was of a double type, but that makes more sense now that I think about it.

Comment: @AdrianMole the 'input' hex is in the form of a character string, so will try this out too! Thank you again

Comment: Re “this obviously involves dubious levels of rounding”: What do you find dubious? If a C implementation uses a base-two floating-point format (such as IEEE-754 binary formats), then a hexadecimal floating-point representation in a string is converted to `double` with `strtod` or `scanf`, then it is correctly rounded, per C 2018 7.22.1.3 5: “If the subject sequence has the hexadecimal form and `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2, the value resulting from the conversion is correctly rounded.” If the string has no more digits than can fit in a `double`, then correct rounding produces an exact result.

Comment: @harold There is not rounding needed with OP's `-0x1.f8b791cafcdefp+4`.

Comment: @Hday "My current method is to convert from hexadecimal to a double, then convert this to IEEE754 representation" --> Post the code that implements that method.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica a nice coincidence, but it's not necessary. If there was rounding, that would be exactly the right amount of rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

union ieee754 {
    uint64_t i;
    double f;
};

int main()
{
    char str[] = "-0x1.f8b791cafcdefp+4";
    union ieee754 val;

    val.f = strtod(str, (char **)NULL);     // might better to check error
    printf("%"PRIX64"\n", val.i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C03F8B791CAFCDEF
```

Alternatively, here is the direct calculation from the substring
just with the bit operations based on the binary64 definition of IEEE754.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    // "-0x1.f8b791cafcdefp+4" is composed of follows:
    uint64_t sign = 1;                          // negative value
    uint64_t exponent = 4 + 1023;               // +1023 offset
    uint64_t fraction = 0xf8b791cafcdef;        // strip the leading "1." off

    uint64_t val = (sign << 63) | (exponent << 52) | fraction;
    printf("%"PRIX64"\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note I don't intend to spoil OP's motivation. Posted the answer just in case...

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to get something working thanks to @Someprogrammerdude, but wasn't certain about the use of unions so it's great to use this to compare and see what I could do to improve!

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative which directly calculates the value based on the IEEE754 standard. Hope it will also help.

Comment: Apologies, just done so. First time asking a question on StackOverflow. Thank you for the further alternative solution, really good to develop more of my understanding regarding C and hexadecimal/IEEE754 use in general!

Comment: It is my pleasure if I could be a help. I suppose IEEE754 is an interesting topic which covers the arithmetic internal representation and the bitwise operation with C, filling the gap between integers and floats.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from hex representation to IEEE754 `double` representation will only involve rounding if there are more decimals than the precision of the `double` type.  This can happen if the textual representation was produced from a `long double`.

Using `strtod()` is the best way to handle this.